# How can I start a graphical widget without control flow getting stuck in its main loop in python?

Tags: parallel-processing, pygame, python-multithreading

I am designing the program structure for an upcoming project right now and I'm stuck on the following issue:
Boiled down to its most important elements my program is split into two files `logic.py` and `oscilloscope.py`. 
 
In the logic.py I initialize a device on `/dev/input/..` and set up filters for signal processing and so on. In oscilloscope.py I have an oscilloscope implementation using Pygame that should interpret/display input coming from the registered input device.
Now I have a main loop in `logic.py` that continuously listens to input coming from the device and then forwards the processed data to the oscilloscope but also I have the main loop from the Pygame oscilloscope implementation.
How do I prevent my program control flow from getting stuck in the Pygame main loop when initializing the oscilloscope from `logic.py` like so:

```
from oscilloscope import *
...
... #initializing filters to use, device to listen to etc.
...
self.osc = Oscilloscope(foo, bar) #creating an instance of an oscilloscope implemented with Pygame

self.osc.main() #calling the main loop of the oscilloscope. This handles all the drawing and updating screen.

#usually the flow would stop here as it is stuck in the Pygame main loop
#I need it to not get stuck so I can call the second main loop.

self.main() #captures and processes data from /dev/input/... sends processed data to the Pygame oscilloscope to draw it.
```

As there is not any actual code yet I hope the comments clarify what I want to do.

Comment: could you provide some more code. it is very difficult to work with what you have given at the moment. especially the `main()` loop

Comment: Mhhm sorry there isn't any actual code yet.. still in the planning phase but I'll try a and edit my question to make the problem more clear

Comment: Also, I don't know much about parallel processing but you might want to check out: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: (and I understand that my suggestion may just be theoretical):

You call the `self.osc.main()` loop from the `self.main()` loop. To do that, you will have to edit your `self.osc.main()` function so that it does not run forever but only once. You keep the `self.main()` loop the same and call the `self.osc.main()` once every loop.

INSTEAD OF WHAT YOU ARE DOING NOW WHICH IS SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
def main(): #This is the self.osc.main() function
    while True: #run forever
        doSomething()

def main(): #This is the self.main() function
    while True: #also run forever
        doSomethingElse()
```

YOU CAN DO THIS INSTEAD:

```
def main(): #This is the self.osc.main() function
    doSomething() #notice I removed the loop. It only runs once. This is because the looping is handled by the other main() function (the one you call self.main())

def main(): #This is the self.main() function
    while True: #also run forever
        self.osc.main() #since we have now changed the self.osc.main() loop to run only once
        doSomethingElse()
```

I Hope That Helps.

Comment: Haha oh yeah I didn't even think of that...funny how sometimes you get stuck thinking in one direction only^^ I'll leave this question open for another day and will accept your answer if no other suggestions come in.  Cheers!

Comment: Sure. I do realize that this is not the prettiest of solutions to your question.